# Bypassing Element When Href has no Attribute

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a situation where I need to extract the hyperlink of a href of a collection of elements for a given class name.  The line of vba code that I have to do this is the following:

```
For Each ele In ie.Document.all
    If ele.className = “Result” Then
        myStringVar = ele.Children(0).getAttribute("href")
    End If
Next ele
```

It works fine when the href hyperlink exists.  However, I get "run-time error 424: Object Required" when the hyperlink is missing.  My guess is that I need to set a conditional statement to check whether the hyperlink exists first before setting the value of myStringVar.  But I'm stuck with the syntax to check for null or empty values of href.  I'm sure the solution is simple.  Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `If ele.Children(0).getAttribute("href") Is Nothing Then` to check whether the href attribute is present in the element before trying to "read" it.

Also, you can use `getElementsByClassName("Result")` to create a collection (array).

Comment: Nathan, thanks.  But I'm still getting the same error 424.  I checked where is failing and it's because even though the class "Result" exists for that given record, the href hyperlink is missing.

Comment: The innertext is also missing.